# Copy Xml node to another xml node using xsl

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have XML file formatted as below. and it needs to change prior to convert to HTML,

The XML file contains.

```
<dmodule>
      <identAndStatusSection>
      <dmAddress>            
          <dmIdent>

          </dmIdent>
          <dmAddressItems>
            <issueDate day="01" month="11" year="2013"/>
            <dmTitle>
              <techName>LP Compressor (LPC)  Fan Module</techName>
              <infoName>Disassemble Procedure</infoName>
            </dmTitle>
          </dmAddressItems>                     
        </dmAddress>
       </identAndStatusSection>
      <content>
    <procedure>
    <commonInfo>
    <title>           
    <inlineSignificantData significantParaDataType="psd51">TASK 72-31-00-030-001</inlineSignificantData> LP Compressor (LPC) Fan Module - Disassemble
    </title>
    <commonInfoDescrPara>
    <title>General</title>
    <para>This TASK gives the procedure to disassemble the LP Compressor (Fan) Module.</para>

    </commonInfoDescrPara>
    </commonInfo>
    </procedure>
    </content>
    </dmodule>
```

I would like to format the XML as below and copy the title node into the identAndStatusSection tag

```
     <dmodule>
      <identAndStatusSection>
      <dmAddress>            
          <dmIdent>

          </dmIdent>
          <dmAddressItems>
            <issueDate day="01" month="11" year="2013"/>
            <dmTitle>
              <techName>LP Compressor (LPC)  Fan Module</techName>
              <infoName>Disassemble Procedure</infoName>
            </dmTitle>
          </dmAddressItems>                     
        </dmAddress>
        <title>           <inlineSignificantData significantParaDataType="psd51">TASK 72-31-00-030-001</inlineSignificantData> LP Compressor (LPC) Fan Module - Disassemble
</title>
       </identAndStatusSection>
      <content>
    <procedure>
    <commonInfo>

    <commonInfoDescrPara>
    <title>General</title>
    <para>This TASK gives the procedure to disassemble the LP Compressor (Fan) Module.</para>

    </commonInfoDescrPara>
    </commonInfo>
    </procedure>
    </content>
    </dmodule>
```

move the `<title> </title>` into the `<identAndStatusSection> </identAndStatusSection>`

how would I do this using XSL sheet?

Answer (score 0):

You can start with an `identity transform` that will copy the input XML contents to the output as is.

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Modify the `<identAndStatusSection>` template and copy its existing contents along with the `<title>` under the `<commonInfo>`

```
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//commonInfo/title" />
</xsl:copy>
```

For the `<commonInfo>` template, copy all the nodes except the `<title>` node.

```
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::title)]" />
</xsl:copy>
```

The complete XSLT and output are as below.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="identAndStatusSection">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//commonInfo/title" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="commonInfo">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::title)]" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
<dmodule>
    <identAndStatusSection>
        <dmAddress>
            <dmIdent />
            <dmAddressItems>
                <issueDate day="01" month="11" year="2013" />
                <dmTitle>
                    <techName>LP Compressor (LPC) Fan Module</techName>
                    <infoName>Disassemble Procedure</infoName>
                </dmTitle>
            </dmAddressItems>
        </dmAddress>
        <title>
            <inlineSignificantData significantParaDataType="psd51">
                TASK 72-31-00-030-001
            </inlineSignificantData>
            LP Compressor (LPC) Fan Module - Disassemble
        </title>
    </identAndStatusSection>
    <content>
        <procedure>
            <commonInfo>
                <commonInfoDescrPara>
                    <title>General</title>
                    <para>This TASK gives the procedure to disassemble the LP Compressor (Fan) Module.</para>
                </commonInfoDescrPara>
            </commonInfo>
        </procedure>
    </content>
</dmodule>
```